# How to fix dynamic href that doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a dynamic href within that the map; however when I click on the button it doesn't seem to change the route. Also, I cannot use Link as it tells me that I cannot use it outside of the router

```
const categories = [];
const menuItems= [];

{this.state.breweries.slice(0,10).map((brewery) =>
  categories.push(brewery.brewery_type)
)}

const uniqueCategories = Array.from(new Set(categories));

uniqueCategories.sort(function(a, b){
if(a < b) { return -1; }
if(a > b) { return 1; }
return 0;
})

const optionTemplate = uniqueCategories.map(v => (
  <MenuItem className="cat-dropdown" key={v.id}>
    <a href={`/` + v}>{v}</a>
  </MenuItem>
));
```

Comment: Can you please add the value of `uniqueCategories` too.

Comment: since `v` seems to be an object `<a href={'/' + v}>` cannot work

Comment: How is v an object?

Comment: `v.id` suggests that `v` is an object...

Comment: if `v` is not an object `key={v.id}` would not work....

Comment: Then how do I take the value?

Comment: according to the first comment it would help to see the value of `uniqueCategories`

Comment: It is an array with these: 0: "brewpub", 1: "contract", 2: "micro"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could print out the javascript object so we can see the properties, ex. `console.log(uniqueCategories);` above the line `const optionTemplate = ...`

Comment: The problem is that no matter what I put in the href it won't work, the object doesn't affect it with anything in this case